# freepbx Astarisk a2billing route customer to customer calls without using outside provider

Tags: asterisk

I am using a2billing with asterisk and I right when make Clint A makes a call to Clint B the calls goes via an outside provider and comes back to asterisk and then a2billing calls Clint B.

So:

Client A calls Client B with DID
a2billing chooses the cheapest route
A2billing routes call to outside sip trunk provider.
Outside sip trunk provider receives the call and calls my the outside number and call comes back to my PBX.
A2billing then looks at the DID and call the client B

I want cut out the outside sip trunk provider and route the call internally as both client  a and client b have bought service from me adn are connected to the same PBX but I am paying the outside sip trunk provider for no reason.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use trunk with type Local and create custom dialplan to access your sipfriends/dids.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+local+channels

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that but I'm new to this. Perhaps you could guide me to a tutorial or make one. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you are new, you have read book, for example ORellys 'Asterisk The Future of Telephony". Sorry, no way guide you over all rules in one answer.